# How can I omit the source links in JsDoc?

Tags: jsdoc, jsdoc3

What's the easiest way to cause JsDoc to leave out the source links?  Do I have to define my own template?

Comment: downvote if you will but please comment why?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

If you use the default template, then use a configuration file with `templates.default.outputSourceFiles` set to `false`. For instance:

```
{
    "templates": {
        "default": {
            "outputSourceFiles": false
        }
    }
}
```

You'd pass the path to this file to jsdoc using the `-c` option on the command line.

I don't see this option documented in any actual jsdoc documentation. I've found it mentioned in [this issue](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/208) and [this one](https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc/issues/454).

The template is the entity providing this functionality so if you use another template than the default one, you have to check its documentation to find whether there is a setting you can set to do this.

Comment: To complete you may need to set both

    "outputSourceFiles"     : false,
    "outputSourcePath"      : false,

as read on  https://github.com/terryweiss/docstrap#configuring-the-template

Comment: @Chris That's true if you are using Docstrap, and this ties into my last paragraph about using templates other than the default one. I just grepped the latest stable release of jsdoc for `outputSourcePath` and it is nowhere to be found.

Answer (score 1):

In order to remove source file links, we need to create a file named `jsdoc.json` and add:

```
{
    "templates":{
      "default":{
        "outputSourceFiles":false
      }
    }
}
```

Then run:

```
jsdoc -c jsdoc.json calculator.js
```

Here `calculator.js` is the main file (your actual file that is going to be documented) and `jsdoc.json` is the configuration file. To run the configuration file I used `–c` option.

So, basically all you need to do is to just create a file called `jsdoc.json` and add the above mentioned code and save it. After saving run this command:

```
jsdoc -c jsdoc.json calculator.js
```